# How to fix inode 2 on a FreeBSD ufs filesystem

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, ufs

My FreeBSD 11.1 system keeps panic-ing with this:

kernel: panic: ufs_dirbad: /mnt: bad dir ino 2 at offset 0: mangled entry

For such an error most forums suggest an older article (http://phaq.phunsites.net/2007/07/01/ufs_dirbad-panic-with-mangled-entries-in-ufs/) where the final solution is clearing the broken inode using the filesystem debugger.

So bad I am more or less confident that inode 2 is not a simple, regular inode but it is related to the root filesystem so I am not that willing to clear it.

Does anyone have any alternative ideas how to fix this? A have already run fsck in single user mode both using and not using the journal but still no luck.

Comment: Whatever you do, backup your system now by taking a disk image with an USB-bootable emergency util of your choice, and only then attempt to fix your system.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates structural problems of the drive sometimes. Sometimes it happens after power failure. No matter what you do - first backup immediately. Second is boot into single user mode and perform the fsck -yf on drive. After fsck backup again. It can work further or you can replace it with another known good drive.